# Check if element is in viewport and pass it to function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of elements, which are lazy-loaded. And now I want to parse them one after another. Therefore I have to determine if they are in viewport. And when they are, I want to pass them to a other function to parse them.

```
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I scroll, I want to check if the element is in the viewport(loaded) and when it is, I want to pass it to my parse function.

parse:

```
parseItem() {
        const url = article.getElementsByClassName('js-listitem')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
        const title = article.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerText;
        // do stuff...
      }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: BTW, elements could be loaded and yet not be in the viewport. So which one do you mean?

Comment: if they are loaded, I want to parse them right away

Comment: What do you mean by `parsing elements`? Can you also include the parse function here?

Comment: basically I want to pull the title, date and other text from the DOMElement. I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onload` event on the document to check when the document has loaded:

```
document.onload = function() {
  parseItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `MutationObserver`. This way I can watch if elements get loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver